# What is the hook to detect if a file or a folder was updated?

Tags: java, objective-c, hook

I am looking for the right "Hook" on Mac OS X, Linux and Windows to detect when a folder and/or file gets updated.

I am using JAVA and Object-C for the MAC.

Thanks in advance.

Also if you have any tips to go on doing this, will be truly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Java library that does this stuff - especially not cross platform.

On Windows the Win32 API offers such functionality though with the [ReadDirectoryChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  function.

Writing a small c wrapper that's called per JNI seems not too hard - the problem is probably finding out how to implement the basic featureset that can be supported by all three platforms.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you should look at [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)